# javascript - using reduce to group by, how do I sum (typescript)

Tags: javascript, reduce

Using typescript, I have my javascript successfully using the reduce function to group by but I can't figure out how to sum another property.

Right now everything is being grouped by property: pacct. (successfully)

I am trying to sum property: quantity.

Can someone please assist?

here is my export interface from another .ts

```
export interface TradeData {
  id: number;
  filedate: Date;
  poffic: string;
  pacct: string;
  quantity: number;
  sector: string;
  psdsC1: string;
  name: string;
  bbsymbol: string;
  last_price: number;
  deltasettlement: number;
}
```

here is my code using reduce

```
const result = trades.reduce((groupedAccounts, trade) => {
  const account = trade.pacct;
  if (groupedAccounts[account] == null) groupedAccounts[account] = [];
  groupedAccounts[account].push(trade);
  return groupedAccounts;
}, {} as Record<string, TradeData[]>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll give `reduce` an initial value of `0`, and then for each trade, we add the quantity to the total.

```
const sum = trades.reduce((total, trade) => total + trade.quantity, 0);
```

The returned value of the function is the next value for `total`, so you could think of it like this:

```js
const callback = (total, trade) => total + trade.quantity;

const initialValue = 0;

let total = initialValue;

for (const trade of trades) {
    total = callback(total, trade);
}
```

To sum each group, let's loop through each group, and to do that, we'll use `Object.entries`:

```js
const entries = Object.entries(groups);
```

Then we transform each entry by making the value the sum of the group's quantities:

```js
const summed = entries.map(([key, group]) => {
    const sum = group.reduce((total, trade) => total + trade.quantity, 0);

    return [key, sum];
});
```

And finally we turn the entries back into an object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const transformed = Object.fromEntries(summed);
```

Comment: thank you, but how would I use this in my reduce function for grouping them?

Comment: So you want to sum all the trades in each group?

Comment: yes, similar to group by and sum in sql.  I am looking for the sum of each group

Comment: If you go through each group you can still use the answer above to sum each group

Comment: I finally was able to use your code and create my end result.  so THANK YOU! One final thing, how do I put these end results in the original TradeData[] formatting.  The reason being, I want to push this to a store and have react display results.